# How to distribute $N$ items into $M$ groups the "most" random way?

Tags: random, algorithmic-randomness

There are $N$ "items" $s_1, s_2, ..., s_N$ and $M$ "buckets" with capacities $c_1, c_2, ..., c_M$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{M}c_j = N$.
In a document I'm reading (some industry application), an algorithm of random filling of buckets is *roughly* described as following.

Algorithm 1.

> until all buckets are full:
>
> - determine random bucket $m$, $1\leq m\leq M$
> - determine random item $i$, $1\leq i\leq N$
> - put item $i$ into bucket $m$

I would do this as following, though. (We work with Python and want to avoid for-loops in the programming code).

Algorithm 2.

- randomly permute the indices of items
- put the first $c_1$ items into 1st bucket, the next (starting from $c_1+1$) $c_2$ items into 2nd bucket and so on.

Are these two approaches equivalent in the sense of randomness (I guess)?
Or do two random pickings in Algorithm 1 make it "more" random than the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that the existing solution allows for duplicates while yours doesn't. Other than that both seem uniformly distributed from symmetry.